# Laravel - "file does not exist or is not readable", but the file is moved successfully

Tags: laravel

I get the follow error:

```
The "C:\xampp\tmp\php49D8.tmp" file does not exist or is not readable.
```

But the file is copied successfully

My controller code is:

```
$fileResult=$file->move(self::UPLOAD_DIR, $name_file);

    if(!$fileResult){
        $result = array("status" => "500",
        "error"=> array("error" => "Error in the file move"));
        return response(json_encode( $result ), $result["status"])
        ->header("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }
```

Screenshot: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sj5uD.jpg)

Why can be the problem?

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be coming from code that you've shared.

Answer (score 0):

Call $validator->fails() can delete uploading file

Comment: But the file is moved successfully. I try my code without $validator->fails() and doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$file = $request->file('file');//get your file

$fileResult=$file->move(self::UPLOAD_DIR, $file->getClientOriginalName());
```